# Is it possible to acces a method int inside another method?

Tags: java, methods

First of all I am new to JAVA, so I still dont understand everything and how it works. But I was working on something and was wondering if it could be done like this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static int calc(){   

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String number1 = sc.nextLine();
        int y = Integer.parseInt(number1);

        System.out.println("+");

        String number2 = sc.nextLine();
        int z = Integer.parseInt(number2);

        int Result = y + z;
        sc.close();
        return Result;

    }
    public static void printText(){

        System.out.println(Result);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        calc();
        printText();            
    }
}
```

In the first method I was calculating the "Result" and in the second I just wanted it to make it so that it takes the "Result" and prints it.. but How I understand is that what happens in a method stays in the method. But I was wondering if it is possible to let method "printText" access the int from "calc".

I know I could place the code into the main and print it from there, but still it buggs me if it could be done like that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't access a local variable from a different method, no. (Once the method has completed, the local variable doesn't exist any more.) However, you can use the return value from your `calc` method, and pass that to the `printText` method:

```
public static void printText(int result) {
    System.out.println(result);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int result = calc();
    printText(result);            
}
```

Comment: Way to correct and not interesting. Should not you pass delegate of some sort to first method to capture local variable and use it later ? :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to do something like that<sup>**1**</sup>, you would need to give `Result` **visibility**. Since your methods are `static` it would also need to be `static`. Also, don't call `close` on a `Scanner` wrapping `System.in` (that's a global, and you can't re-open it). Something like,

```
private static int Result;
public static int calc(){   
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String number1 = sc.nextLine();
    int y = Integer.parseInt(number1);
    System.out.println("+");
    String number2 = sc.nextLine();
    int z = Integer.parseInt(number2);
    Result = y + z;
    return Result;
}
```

<sup>**1**<sub>As opposed to using the returned value, or passing it into your second method.</sub></sup>

Comment: You didn't **remove** `int` before `Result` as in my answer; thus you [shadowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) `Result`.